# Receive parameters in godot by url

Tags: wordpress, url, parameters, godot

I load a game in Url with params (like: [www.mysite.com/game/25](http://www.mysite.com/game/25)).

How I can get the Url string or only params in GDScript?

Comment: It is an HTML export of the game, right? If that is the case, you should be able to use JavaScript to access the url. I'm not sure what you mean by params. Edit: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URL#Syntax

Comment: Manipulating the url with javascript does not allow me to interact with godot's gdscript language, there is no interface.

Comment: I suggest you go the other way around. Try to use JavaScript from Godot. See [JavaScript](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_javascript.html), you can use it to eval JavaScritp code, including getting the URL. With that said, there is an interface from JavaScript to Godot, if you really want to do that, see [HTML5](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/tutorials/platform/platform_html5.html). You can pass the URL as a "command line argument" and then read it with [OS](https://docs.godotengine.org/en/stable/classes/class_os.html).

Comment: Good news, there is a new Godot <-> JavaScript interface available on Godot 3.4 (in beta at the time of writing).